# 'Table1' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, eclipse, hash, hashtable

When compiling this code I received the following error..

```
tables/cuckoo.c: In function 'new_cuckoo_hash_table':
tables/cuckoo.c:35:9: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'CuckooHashTable')
  table1 -> slots = malloc((sizeof *table1->slots) * size);
         ^
tables/cuckoo.c:35:42: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'CuckooHashTable')
  table1 -> slots = malloc((sizeof *table1->slots) * size);
                                          ^
In file included from tables/cuckoo.c:11:0:
tables/cuckoo.c:36:15: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'CuckooHashTable')
  assert(table1->slots);
               ^
tables/cuckoo.c:37:8: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'CuckooHashTable')
  table1->inuse = malloc((sizeof *table1->inuse) * size);
        ^
tables/cuckoo.c:37:40: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'CuckooHashTable')
  table1->inuse = malloc((sizeof *table1->inuse) * size);
                                        ^
In file included from tables/cuckoo.c:11:0:
tables/cuckoo.c:38:18: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'CuckooHashTable')
     assert(table1->inuse);
```

I think the errors did not stop just there, all the variables inside `new_cuckoo_hash_table` are probably mishandled...

I understand that has something to do with me not declaring the type for my `table1`, but what confuses me is that I have had a struct which contained `InnerTable *table1`, hopefully someone can point out the cause of this error.

Any corrections would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "cuckoo.h"

typedef struct inner_table {
    int64 *slots;   // array of slots holding keys
    bool  *inuse;   // is this slot in use or not?
} InnerTable;

// a cuckoo hash table stores its keys in two inner tables
struct cuckoo_table {
    InnerTable *table1; // first table
    InnerTable *table2; // second table
    int size;           // size of each table
};


// initialise a cuckoo hash table with 'size' slots in each table
CuckooHashTable *new_cuckoo_hash_table(int size) {
    InnerTable table1;
    assert(size < MAX_TABLE_SIZE && "error: table has grown too large!");
    table1 -> slots = malloc((sizeof *table1->slots) * size);
    assert(table1->slots);
    table1->inuse = malloc((sizeof *table1->inuse) * size);
    assert(table1->inuse);
    return NULL;

    //return NULL;
}
```

EDIT:

To those who need more info about `CuckooHashTable`

```
typedef struct cuckoo_table CuckooHashTable
```

Comment: At which line do you get the error?

Comment: `table1 -> slots = malloc((sizeof *table1->slots) * size);` But I do think I'm doing something horribly wrong overall in this function tho..

Comment: You never declare a variable `table1`. `table1` is a field of `struct cuckoo_table`.

Comment: use cuckoo_table.table1

Comment: @MichaelWalz so I did this `InnerTable table1;`, do you reckon it's the right way to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, that looks like a good start, but it's hard to tell if it's really correct without knowing more about this `CuckooHashTable` stuff and without knowing what you're _actually_ trying to achieve.

Comment: Is `new_cuckoo_hash_table` supposed to allocate memory for a `CuckooHashTable` (which is presumably a `typedef` for `struct cuckoo_table`?) and set `->table1` and `->table2` to more allocated memory for the inner tables?

Comment: @MichaelWalz so now the error still persists but in a different form... 
`error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'InnerTable')`

Comment: @IanAbbott exactly.

Comment: We need to know m ore about `CuckooHashTable`. What exactly is `CuckooHashTable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have to initialize another pointer that is used to direct things at `table1` and `table2`

Like this:

```
newtable->table = malloc(sizeof (*newtable->table));
```

Then start working on `slots` and `inuse` in a similar fashion.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

So you probably want something like this (just guessing from comments and looking into my crystal ball):

```
CuckooHashTable *new_cuckoo_hash_table(int size) {
    assert(size < MAX_TABLE_SIZE && "error: table has grown too large!");

    CuckooHashTable *newtable = malloc(sizeof(CuckooHashTable));
    assert(newtable);
    newtable->table1 = malloc(sizeof(InnerTable));
    assert(newtable->table1);
    newtable->table1->slots = malloc((sizeof *table1->slots) * size);
    assert(table1->slots);
    newtable->table1->inuse = malloc((sizeof *table1->inuse) * size);
    assert(table1->inuse);

    return newtable;
}
```

This is untested, non error checking code, there may be typos and the code may not compile.

Comment: to your question in the comment, `typedef struct cuckoo_table CuckooHashTable`.

Comment: @CookieJar you should mention this in the question.

Comment: will do, thanks! And apparently after the changes you suggested there are still some leftovers stuck in there. I did try to add one new line to my original code which is  `InnerTable *table1` and no more errors... Maybe I'm also looking thru crystal ball...And I also know for a fact that mine attempt is probably not the right way to do it....